# Checkbox checkedchanged is not firing which is inside of listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, checkbox

Here is my LayoutTemplate of Listview. I have kept `CheckBox` in side of it and I want post back of page when I checked to checkbox. But here Problem is that I am not able to  fire checkbox OnCheckedChanged event. And even I am not getting any event of checkbox in my properties windows. So if anybody have any idea about this problem then please help me.

```
<LayoutTemplate>
     <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
           <tr>
              <td>
                  <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCheck" runat="server" CommandName="ChkChange" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:CheckBox>
             </td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
</LayoutTemplate>
```

Comment: Can you please paste whole list view control along with events and code?

Answer (score 2):

You didnt define a method to call, so the checkbox doesnt know what method to use.

```
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCheck" OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked"
    runat="server" CommandName="ChkChange" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:CheckBox>
```

This one gose in your codebehind.

```
void Check_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)   
{  
  //do something
}
```

Comment: I know that i have not define any OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked" in my code but the problem is that i am not getting any event list in property window in my case.

Comment: I quite dont understand what the problem is. What do you mean with you have no event list? if you open the property window and you didnt define anything, there should be a empty box with the label "OnCheckedChanged". CommandName etc. are also there. Put there "Check_Clicked" or define it directly in code. It doesnt make any difference. I actually never use the property window.